# CSS - Centering li under previous li

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to center an li under a previous li for a drop down menu.  The best thing I could come up with is to use a negative margin to move the list to the left, but this doesn't work uniformly.  Any ideas?

```
#navigation {
    height: 50px;
    width: 960;
}
#navigation ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 40px;
}
#navigation ul li ul {
    display:none;
    width: 240px;
}
#navigation li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 0 0 -35px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: just from a user perspective...the centred menu items doesn't look nice....follow the default left-alignment

Comment: could maybe use `text-align:center` on the li's and then wrap your text in a span or div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you'll need to add `position:relative` for the `#navigation ul li`, and then position the `#navigation li:hover ul` using the

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -52px;
```

Doing so, you'd, at first, position the `ul` to the half of the parent `li` and then would move it to the left according to it's dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this coding:

```
#navigation ul li {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 30px;
    width: 80px;
}
```